# How do I hide my custom css overflow in IE8?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have made a script that uses pure css to toggle image, image caption and text. When I run this in IE8 I can all of the elements at once. The scripting for this is quite extensive so out of convenience I have made this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/atnD8/2/). I need to hide the `cascade-overlay-content` and have tried to use `overflow:hidden;` and adding it changed nothing as I am still able to see all elements after adding it everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `{ position: relative; }` to the parent element. Sometimes it helps in old IE versions, especially IE7. Besides, make sure the parent has `{ overflow: hidden; }`.